# Reading from one file, export to another

Tags: java, string, file, export

I am trying to read `GPX`-data from a `.txt` file and then exporting it to another `.txt` file(just as a test in a bigger project). But every time I try and run it, the `.txt` file appears to be empty.

This is the code I'm using so far:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JFileChooser Chooser = new JFileChooser();        
    try{
        String Metadata = new Scanner(Chooser.getSelectedFile()).useDelimiter("</metadata").next();
        String Points = new Scanner(Chooser.getSelectedFile()).useDelimiter("<wpt>").next();
        File Test = new File("Test.txt");
        PrintWriter Output = new PrintWriter(Test);
        Output.print(Points);
    }  catch (IOException EXE) {
        System.out.println(EXE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        JFileChooser Chooser = new JFileChooser();        
        try{
            String Metadata = new Scanner(Chooser.getSelectedFile()).useDelimiter("</metadata").next();
            String Points = new Scanner(Chooser.getSelectedFile()).useDelimiter("<wpt>").next();
            File Test = new File("Test.txt");
            PrintWriter Output = new PrintWriter(Test);
            Output.write(Points);
            Output.flush() // added code 
        }  catch (IOException EXE) {
            System.out.println(EXE);
        }
    }
```

Output.flush() will write your data as it clear the buffer and write data
to the file

Answer (score 0):

Flush the file data into txt file

add  `Output.flush()`

```
 PrintWriter Output = new PrintWriter(Test);
                Output.print(Points);
                Output.flush();
```

instead of

```
PrintWriter Output = new PrintWriter(Test);
        Output.print(Points);
```